# AWS Lambda : Can those event can be integrated with API Management Tools?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What i am trying to do:

i am planning to write my mobile back-end api using aws lambda. From the recent releases i got the info, that all events can triggered via aws-sdk on any platform including (android and iOS).

i have done POC for that, and its working fine. But how to manage all those events for metrics? security (OAuth)? Metering?. I know all these can be done via an api management tool. So i planned and chose CA API Management Gateway for doing these.

Where i am struck:

How can i integrate those lambda events in CA API Management Gateway or Any other API Management Gateway?

[image: Below diagram show my architecture]

Extra Question's i have:

1. Can this be Done?
2. Will the api scale?
3. Is it a good idea of building all api in lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy solution for this, I'm encountering a similar problem. It would be great if Amazon could provide an API gateway functionality for Lambda but they don't seem to at present. It feels like a big hole in their service.

If your CA API gateway has the ability to execute code you could write an intermediary that utilizes the Amazon mobile SDKs [as detailed here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/wt-user-app-android.html), otherwise you might need to develop an intermediary application that performs a similar role.

The problem with developing an intermediary application however is then you will need to utilize EC2 compute resources and configure auto scaling mechanisms yourself. It would be much better if Amazon could provide this as a managed service.

---

### Update

Amazon has just announced an [API Gateway](http://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) service.